# How to Increment position of ArrayList on swipe in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I practicing a app. where i made a Place Array, A grid view which displays 0th position in `GridView` and 1st position in `ImageView` for grid view, 2nd position is displayed when clicked on the gridview in another activity called answer. in answer activity when swiped i want it to go to another question but am not getting it. Can u help me Out.here is the code bellow.

```
public class QuestionsActivity extends Activity {
    public Place[] myPlaceArray = new Place[]{
        new Place(1, "settings" , "1. Given the choice of"),
        new Place(2, "settings" , "2. Would you like to "),
        new Place(3, "settings" , "3. Before making a telephone call"),
        new Place(4, "settings" , "4. What would constitute "),
        new Place(5, "settings" , "5. When did you last"),
        new Place(6, "settings" , "6. If you were "),
        new Place(7, "settings" , "7. Do you have a secret "),
        new Place(8, "settings" , "8. Name three things you "),
        new Place(9, "settings" , "9. For what in your "),
        new Place(10, "settings" , "10. If you could ")
    };

    private GridView numgridView;
    private ArrayAdapter mPlaceAdapter;
    public int clickedPosition;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question_activity);

        numgridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.numGrid);
        mPlaceAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.question_numbers_view,myPlaceArray);

        if (numgridView!=null){
            numgridView.setAdapter(mPlaceAdapter);
        }
        numgridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                clickedPosition = position;
                Log.v("PLACE", myPlaceArray[position].Question);
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionsActivity.this, answer.class);
                intent.putExtra("theAnswer",myPlaceArray[position].Question );

                intent.putExtra("theNextAnswer",myPlaceArray[clickedPosition ++].Question ); // this is what i tried but it dint work
                intent.putExtra("thePreviousAnswer",myPlaceArray[clickedPosition --].Question ); // this is what i tried but it dint work

                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(QuestionsActivity.this, "Touch And Hold To Copy The Text",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

i passed it to another activity with key and when swiped i want it to go to the next question.

```
public class answer extends Activity implements AdColonyAdAvailabilityListener, AdColonyAdListener {
    TextView textView;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.answer);
    AdColony.configure(this, "version:1.0,store:google", APP_ID, ZONE_ID);
    AdColony.addAdAvailabilityListener(this);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    textView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("theAnswer"));
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        }
    });
    textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
        public boolean onSwipeRight() {
            Toast.makeText(answer.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            textView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("thePreviousAnswer"));
            return true;
            // here when i swiped i want it to go to next question
        }
            public boolean onSwipeLeft() {
                Toast.makeText(answer.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("theNextAnswer"));
                return true;
                //here i want it go to previous question 
            }
        });
    if(AdColony.statusForZone(ZONE_ID).equals("active"))
    {
        textView.setEnabled( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: i did not check all the code, but generally `post increment` "clickedPosition ++" will send current value then increase it by 1 , so try to use `pre increment` "++clickedPosition" and see the result, it may solve the issue (same concept for decrement (--)

Comment: I tried it the swiping action working only once. when swiped again it should go to the next answer that is the ClickedPosition should increment and saved, when swiped again then Increment and save.